# Signal wave form change as it travels down the transmission line

Tags: transmission-line, characteristic-impedance

This question is not about reflections that will distort the signal which contains many high frequency components.

I would like to know what the signal looks like (changes in shape, attenuation, etc.) as it travels down the transmission line.

How can I calculate this? I just want to think of a transmission line as a filter (like low pass filter.) I would like to know how I can incorporate basic ideas, such as systems theory, Laplace transform, Kirchoff voltage law, impedance divider (like resistor divider) and basic circuit operations to find shape changes that occur on the complex signal (like a digital signal) I inserted to the transmission line.

I am assuming that :

1. In highly idealized cases, the source and the load and the transmission line have the same characteristic impedance, therefore there will be no signal reflection.

2. The transmission line is lossy and complex and its characteristic impedance is fixed along the transmission line.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations

Comment: "Solutions of the telegrapher's equations as circuit components" is the section I need to study I guess for my problem. I looked it up again and it seems fine. Thank you for your comment

Comment: The easiest and most practical way is to run simulations on a simulator. The hardest part is the learning curve if you've never used one. On the other hand, everyone interested in EE design needs to learn to use one.